# Best game in the last 3 days

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have question about using this phrase.

For example. If I was cooking lunch everyday meaning Saturday, Sunday and today is Monday lunch time and I cooked lunch again but my family does not like it.

They would say:

> This has been your worst lunch in the last two or three days?

Or another example:

If I am working today 3rd day in the job and my boss gives me the most work today should I tell my friend that:

> This has been the most work I have been given in the last 2 or 3 days?

Thank you for explaining and sorry for asking these maybe stupid questions but I have OCD and cant help myself, I need reassurance.

Comment: I can't even figure out what you are trying to ask. Are you asking if it's okay to say "in the last two or three days"? (Answer: Yes.) Or are you asking if it should be "in the last ***two*** days" or "in the last ***three*** days"? (Answer: use three; it's been three days, not two).

Answer (score 0):

In both of your examples the number of days is 3 (1:Saturday, 2:Sunday, 3:Monday) and the *third* day on the job, so you would say

> This has been your worst lunch in the last *three* days?
>   This has been the most work I have been given in the last *3* days?

The phrase

> for the past

might be used in place of

> in the last

in your example without loss of understanding

> This has been your worst lunch *for the past* three days.
>   This has been the most work I have been given *for the past* 3 days?